# How to Get the currentProgram object in Ghidra?

Tags: python, ghidra

I want to write a python script that can extract and print objects from a ghidra project such as enums and structs and for that I need to call the DataTypeManager from the currentProgram object, but I'm not sure how to call currentProgram in a script that's not in the ghidra python terminal.
Any suggestions or examples?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: currentProgram can be called directly from the terminal with an import:

```
from __main__ import currentProgram
```